# WriteableBitmap Doesn't change pixel color in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, image-processing

I use WriteableBitmap to set pixel in Wpf. but when I used writePixels method to change the color of pixels it's change color to black :(. It's my code snap:

```
            ofdOpen.ShowDialog();
            BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage(new Uri(ofdOpen.FileName));
            WriteableBitmap wbmap = new
            WriteableBitmap(img);
             byte[] pixels = new byte[
   wbmap.PixelHeight*wbmap.PixelWidth*
      wbmap.Format.BitsPerPixel/8];
       pixels[0] =255;
       pixels[1] = 0;
       pixels[2] = 0;
       pixels[3] = 255;
       wbmap.WritePixels(
        new Int32Rect(0, 0,
         wbmap.PixelWidth, wbmap.PixelHeight),
        pixels,
        wbmap.PixelWidth * wbmap.
            Format.BitsPerPixel / 8, 0);

            image1.Source = wbmap;
```

I'm googling too much. but I couldn't find any source about this problem.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's appearing black because you're rewriting the entire contents of the image, not just a few pixels.  Your `pixels` array is declared to be to be the size of the entire image, but you are only setting two of the first four bytes of color data.  So, when you call `WritePixels`, it's redrawing the entire image with the provider color data, which is almost all 0's.

To correct this, only declare the `pixels` array to be the size of the pixels you want to write.

Comment: Tnx dear. I know dear. The entire image is not my problem. My problem is color of the pixels. I'm change color to red. but it's change it to black. I'ts problem. tnx 4 ur attention. when I create bitmap using method it's work fine. But after use bitmap from image it's change it behavior. And change pixel to black. Alpha work fine. but color doesn't change to any color expect Black :(

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, then it's possible that the pixel format of the bitmap you create could be different that than of an image you load.  For example, I used your SO avatar image as a test with the code you posted and the top left pixel is changed to blue.  Its pixel data is written as BGRA.  So, if you were attempting to change a pixel to red, your pixel data would be 0 0 255 0.

Comment: yes that's true. It's work correct. but when I use image source as bitmap the problem occurred. Finally I Found the solution. tnx 4 ur help.

Answer (score 0):

Finllay I found solution:

```
            BitmapImage originalIamge = new BitmapImage();
        originalIamge.BeginInit();
        originalIamge.UriSource = new Uri(ofdOpen.FileName);
        originalIamge.EndInit();
        BitmapSource bitmapSource = new FormatConvertedBitmap(originalIamge, PixelFormats.Bgr32, null, 0);
        wbmap = new WriteableBitmap(bitmapSource);

        h = wbmap.PixelHeight;
        w = wbmap.PixelWidth;
        pixelData = new int[w * h];
        widthInByte = 4 * w;

        wbmap.CopyPixels(pixelData, widthInByte, 0);
        image1.Source = wbmap;
        Point absoluteScreenPos = PointToScreen(Mouse.GetPosition((IInputElement)sender));
        Image img = new Image();
        BitmapImage point = new BitmapImage(
                      new Uri("Images/Dott.png",
                              UriKind.Relative));
        img.Source = point;

        var rt = ((UIElement)image1).RenderTransform;

        var offsetX = rt.Value.OffsetX;

        var offsetY = rt.Value.OffsetY;
        int newX = (int)Mouse.GetPosition((IInputElement)sender).X;
        int newY = (int)Mouse.GetPosition((IInputElement)sender).Y;

        for (int i = 0; i < 400; i++)
        {
            pixelData[i] = 0x000000ff;
        }

        wbmap.WritePixels(new Int32Rect(newX,newY,10,10), pixelData, widthInByte, 0);

        image1.Source = wbmap;
```