Remove Black Background from BitmapImage WinUI 3
First time app developer, I am trying to remove the black from the back of a scanned image. This image is sent by multiple different scanners and saved to the desktop as a PNG. I am trying to take that saved image and remove the black background and display the image in a desktop app.
I have found multiple ways of manipulating a Bitmap but these aren't working for a BitmapImage which is what I am using for WinUI 3.
I have also seen WriteableBitmap but I am unable to use CopyPixel() or any other methods provided.
This is the code I currently have to display the image in the app:
BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
bi.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache;
bi.UriSource = new Uri(back);
this.Front.Source = bi;

An example of what I am looking for in WinUI 3:
Convert Specific BitmapImage Colour to Transparent
Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Turns out VisualStudio was bugging out and didn't show me the Install System.Drawing.Common until restart :(
Was able to solve this with:
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(front);
bitmap.MakeTransparent(Color.Black);
bitmap.Save(front);



I am unable to use CopyPixel() or any other methods provided.

Like.. physically unable? Or you just don't know how? Cause it's pretty trivial to upload pixel data to a WriteableBitmap:
var softwareBitmap = ...;
softwareBitmap.CopyToBuffer(writeableBitmap.PixelBuffer);

And once you build your SoftwareBitmap, you're free to edit it as you wish with regular pointer operations using LockBuffer.

I'll give this a try, I was following this type of direction and I was unable to decipher what usings were needed. All of the examples i were seeing needed system.windows.media.imaging or somthing similar which I was unable to use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17767097/writeablebitmap-doesnt-change-pixel-color-in-wpf

Definitely tried this but upon restart MakeTransparent worked and is condensed for a smaller project. Thank you!
